# confusing usage of construction function of python dict

Tags: python, ansible

When i was reading source code of ansible in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/common/collections.py
i found below snippet of code.

```
class ImmutableDict(Hashable, Mapping):
    """Dictionary that cannot be updated"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._store = dict(*args, **kwargs)
```

i tried to use the same syntax used above with code below, it failed.

```
args = ("name", "jone", "sex", "male")
kwargs = {
    "age": 13,
    "job": "software enginner"
}
d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
print(d)

### error msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/steveguan/code/Work/Test/test_dict.py", line 41, in <module>
    d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

I tried to read official documents in https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict, the document shows the usage is not right.

Comment: I assume the rationality is that `ImmutableDict` will behave precisely like a `dict`. If you try to passing position arguments to `ImmutableDict`, it will fail in precisely the same way as a `dict`. Further, if `dict` is updated to take some positional arguments, `ImmutableDict` will immediately be able to provide the same interface.

Comment: What do you mean "it failed"? How did it fail?

Comment: The error message is clear enough, isn't it?  dict can only accept 0 or 1 positional arguments, but you're attempting to pass 4 of them.

Comment: You would have gotten the exact same error if you tried to pass those arguments to the `ImmutableDict` class you found.

Comment: but why the original author in ansible write the code above, any more trick exists there

Comment: @xiaojueguan  They just did that in ansible as a python-2.7 compatible way of allowing 0 or 1 positional arguments, as dict does.

Answer (score -1):

`(*args)` is used when we're unpacking parameters from function arguments. You don't need to use it.

```
def d(*arr):
    return dict(*arr)

arr = [(1,2),(3,4)]
d(arr)
```

This is the same as

```
arr = [(1,2),(3,4)]
dict(arr)
```